# Error when sourcing my .vimrc

Tags: vimrc, external-command

I've just added this line to my `.vimrc` to be able to open chrome without leaving vim.

```
command GoogleChromeA execute "!google-chrome > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

It works fine however, when I use the command `source $MYVIMRC`, I get this error:

```
E174: command already exists: add ! to replace it
```

How can I fix that?

**Edit:**
I've tried `command!`. It works fine but for some reason the statusline from vim-airline changes:
This is how it usually looks like:
[image]

This is how it looks like after saving (sourcing) the file:
[image]

I could live with it since it just happens when sourcing my `.vimrc` but... it would be better if this could be fixed :)

Comment: Try `command!` instead of `command`. Do you usually source your `vimrc` multiple times in a session?

Comment: I have set an autocommand that source my vimrc every time I save it. This way I can check the changes without having to exit vim and opening it again.

Comment: Why exit Vim? Open a new instance in another terminal, or background Vim and start a new one. For testing vimrc, I'd strongly recommend running a new instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`command` will give an error if a command with that name already exists. Vim has no way of knowing that the command in your vimrc is actually the same command; from Vim's viewpoint it's a "new" command.

You have to use `command!` to override any existing commands.  The same applies to functions; use `function!` to override existing functions. This also works for the shorthand versions (e.g. `comm!`, `fun!`).

Another caveat are autocommands. If you use:

```
autocmd BufNew * some_command()
```

and you reload your vimrc then you will have *two* autocommands defined! Vim has no way to "see" that this autocommand was already executed and installed on startup.

To fix this use `augroup`:

```
" Define a new autocommand group
augroup my_autocmd_name
    " Clear all existing autocommands in this group
    autocmd!

    " This will now always be installed once only
    autocmd BufNew * some_command()
augroup end
```

A third caveat is realizing that not all autocommands are run when you reload your vimrc. Specifically, things like `VimEnter`, `BufReadPost`, `Filetype` `WinEnter`, etc. aren't executed when you type `:source $VIMRC`. This is especially important if you have something like:

```
" Real men use real tabs
set expandtab

" Python programmers aren't real men (augroup omitted for brevity)
autocmd Filetype *.py setlocal noexpandtab
```

If you now reload your vimrc while you have a buffer with a Python file, the `:set` command will reset `expandtab` and the `Filetype` autocommand is never executed to override it for Python files.

---

As for your airline issue − I don't know. [The FAQ](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/wiki/FAQ) recommends running the `:AirlineRefresh` command.

Comment: AirlineRefresh with `autocmd SourceCmd .vimrc AirlineRefresh` should work

Answer (score 0):

Since I discovered that my comment for the airline issue does not quite work, here's an expanded (and hopefully correct) answer:

```
augroup my_autocmd_name
  ...
  autocmd SourceCmd .vimrc execute "source" expand("<afile>") | AirlineRefresh

augroup end
```

`autocmd SourceCmd` will actually prevent vim from sourcing the file so we have to call it ourselves before doing the refresh.