# Toggle highlighting of trailing whitespace

Tags: highlight, whitespace

I put the following lines from [this page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces) into my `~/.vimrc` to highlight trailing whitespace in red:

```
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red
match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd BufWinEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd InsertEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+\%#\@<!$/
autocmd InsertLeave * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd BufWinLeave * call clearmatches()
```

I would like to have this be the default behavior, but be able to toggle this behavior on and off with something like <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>. I found a code snippet from this answer that looks promising. After editing it I had something like this:

```
let g:toggleHighlightWhitespace = 1
function! ToggleHighlightWhitespace(...)
  if a:0 == 1 "toggle behaviour
    let g:toggleHighlightWhitespace = 1 - g:toggleHighlightWhitespace
  endif

  if g:toggleHighlightWhitespace == 1 "normal action, do the hi
    highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red
    match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
    autocmd BufWinEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
    autocmd InsertEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+\%#\@<!$/
    autocmd InsertLeave * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
    autocmd BufWinLeave * call clearmatches()
  else
    call clearmatches()
  endif
endfunction

autocmd BufWinEnter * call ToggleHighlightWhitespace()
autocmd InsertEnter * call ToggleHighlightWhitespace()
autocmd InsertLeave * call ToggleHighlightWhitespace()
autocmd BufWinLeave * call ToggleHighlightWhitespace()
nnoremap <leader>w :call ToggleHighlightWhitespace(1)<cr>
```

With these lines, typing <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> in normal mode gets rid of the highlighting, but as soon as I re-enter insert mode, the highlighting returns. How do I get the toggling to work?

**EDIT**

Thanks to help from Grochmal, my final snippet from `~/.vimrc` is shown below. I split the toggle function into a toggle function and a refresh function for clarity.

```
let g:toggleHighlightWhitespace = 1    
function! ToggleHighlightWhitespace()    
  let g:toggleHighlightWhitespace = 1 - g:toggleHighlightWhitespace     
  call RefreshHighlightWhitespace()    
endfunction    

function! RefreshHighlightWhitespace()    
  if g:toggleHighlightWhitespace == 1 " normal action, do the hi    
    highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red    
    match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/    
    augroup HighLightWhitespace    
      autocmd BufWinEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/    
      autocmd InsertEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+\%#\@<!$/    
      autocmd InsertLeave * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/    
      autocmd BufWinLeave * call clearmatches()    
    augroup END    
  else " clear whitespace highlighting    
    call clearmatches()    
    autocmd! HighLightWhitespace BufWinEnter    
    autocmd! HighLightWhitespace InsertEnter    
    autocmd! HighLightWhitespace InsertLeave    
    autocmd! HighLightWhitespace BufWinLeave    
  endif    
endfunction    

autocmd BufWinEnter * call RefreshHighlightWhitespace()    
autocmd BufWinLeave * call RefreshHighlightWhitespace()    
nnoremap <leader>w :call ToggleHighlightWhitespace()<cr>
```

Comment: From [`:help :autocmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#:autocmd): *When your `.vimrc` file is sourced twice, the autocommands will appear twice. To avoid this, put `:autocmd!` in your `.vimrc` file, before defining autocommands*. See [this](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7063/6698) answer to know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Extraneous `autocmd`

First, you told Vim to call your toggle function every time you enter or leave the insert mode.  i.e. by using the `InsertEnter` and `InsertLeave` events as follows:

```
autocmd InsertEnter * call ToggleHighlightWhitespace()
autocmd InsertLeave * call ToggleHighlightWhitespace()
```

Those events are **not needed there**.  Therefore, kill these two lines.

#### Long standing `autocmd`

On the other hand **these events are needed in the match sections**, because in insert mode you might be typing at spaces at the end of the line:

```
autocmd InsertEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+\%#\@<!$/
autocmd InsertLeave * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
```

Do not kill these `autocmd`s.  But that is not all, these `autocmd`s will trigger `match` whether your toggle is on or off, which is not what a toggle is intended for.

These `autocmd`s need to be disabled when the toggle is off, but there is no way to disable an `autocmd`!  You need to wrap these `autocmd`s inside an `augroup` so they are not *long standing*, i.e. so they can be disabled.

In essence, your condition needs to looks as follows:

```
if g:toggleHighlightWhitespace == 1 "normal action, do the hi
  highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red
  match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
  augroup HighlightWhitespace
  autocmd BufWinEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
  autocmd InsertEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+\%#\@<!$/
  autocmd InsertLeave * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
  autocmd BufWinLeave * call clearmatches()
  augroup END
else
  call clearmatches()   
  autocmd! HighlightWhitespace BufWinEnter
  autocmd! HighlightWhitespace InsertEnter
  autocmd! HighlightWhitespace InsertLeave
  autocmd! HighlightWhitespace BufWinLeave
endif
```

`autocmd!` can only disable an `autocmd` if it is named by an `augroup` (I'm not 100% certain of this statement, but it does work well for the script at hand).

Comment: Deleting those two lines doesn't change the highlighting behavior for me. Re-entering insert mode still turns highlighting back on either way.

Comment: @BenLindsay `autocmd` has the bad habit of sticking around.  Did you exit the vim instance altogether (you should) or just sourced the edited script?  Wait,  i didn't test it properly.  I think i can replicate it with the lines removed.

Comment: Yeah, I exited vim altogether.

Comment: @BenLindsay - i was wrong, or better, i tested the solution poorly.  You actually need to disable the `autocmd`s for the period your toggle is off (whether in insert or normal mode).  I have extensively edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Take into account that vim already includes this highlight functionality. The options [`'list'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27list%27) and [`'listchars`'](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27listchars%27) can be used for that purpose by adding the following lines to vimrc:

```
set list
set listchars=trail:*
```

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of this. I think the setup I have is a little nicer though, since in insert mode, the line my cursor is on doesn't have highlighting turned on but all other lines do. This is nice because as I'm typing a line, I don't like to have every new space highlighted.